# Problem with sticky navbar doesn't scroll like should

Tags: javascript, html, css

At first, I would like to say that I am completely new in JS. I've tried to resolve that for some time, but I can't find a solution. I have a little problem(I hope so, it's little!) with my simple sticky navbar. Exactly it has to be a mistake with `position: fixed;` I would like to achive a sticky effect when navbar will be hide  and `section-feauters` will be apear. I will grateful for solution! It's some of my HTML code

HTML:

```
   <header>
    <nav id="navbar">
        <img src="resources/img/onlinelogomaker-051519-2011-4086.png" class="mainlogo">
        <ul class="main-nav" id="js--main-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Main Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Offer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>

        </ul>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="mobile-nav-icon" onclick="myFunction2()">
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </a>

    </nav>

    <div class="main-header">
            <h1>Get up and let's go to the new natural world</h1>
            <a class="btn btn-join" href="#">Join me!</a>
            <a class="btn btn-read" href="#">Read more</a>
        </div>
</header>
<section class="section-feauters">
        <div class="section group">
            <h2>Leave the old life - You can do it</h2>
            <p class="desc-section-feauters">Do you want to be faster, healthier and better inside? Do you feel the desire in heart? Do you remember the superheroes of your best childhood years? It's not a joke you can try it now! It's not a joke, dare! You won't regret, just <strong>NATURE - ACTIVE!</strong></p>

    </div>
</section>
```

This is css style response for sticky:

```
.main-nav {
    float: right;
    margin: 25px 15px;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main-nav li {

    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px;

}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.2s;


}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
    color: #fbf9ee;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #c47519;

}

/* Nav responsive */


/*Sticky navi*/

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.94);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 13px #dedede;
    z-index: 9999;

}

.sticky .main-nav li a:link,
.sticky .main-nav li a:visited {
    padding: 15px 0;
    color: #555;

}
```

and js

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? hide the navbar when scrolling down?

Comment: I would like to change navbar into .sticky after scrolling down to other section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. I've added just a condition to if statement `sticky && window.pageYOffset> 670` now solution look's like that :

```
function myFunction() {
    var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
    console.log(sticky);

       if (window.pageYOffset > sticky && window.pageYOffset> 670) {
            navbar.classList.add("sticky")
            console.log(sticky);
        } else {
            navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
    }
```

Maybe it will be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Your Navbar Works fine. You don't see it because your body not have enough contents to scroll. Set height to body to see its working

```
body{ height:2000px;}
```

[Check the link](https://jsfiddle.net/0pdokaeq)

Comment: Hi, no height is set at auto. I would like to get effect when section-feauters will be apear